# Can i write dropdown menu without using select element

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, html-select, use-ref

I want to know if its okay to use `<div>` and `<button>` elements instead of using `<select>` and `<option>` in React and make the `<button>` elements controlled.
I want to implement that for styling purposes since `<select>` and `<option>` is limited for styling.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export const FiltersDropdown = () => {

    const currentFilter = useRef('All');

    const handleSelectFilter = (e) => {
        currentFilter.current =  e.target.value;
    }

    return (
        <div className='filters-dropdown'>
            <div className="select-header">
                <p>Filter by Region</p>
                <img src="../images/chevron-down-sharp.svg" alt='dropdown-arrow'></img>
            </div>
            <div className="select-body">
                <button value='All' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>All</button>
                <button value='Africa' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>Africa</button>
                <button value='America' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>America</button>
                <button value='Asia' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>Asia</button>
                <button value='Europe' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>Europe</button>
                <button value='Oceania' className="select-option" onClick={handleSelectFilter}>Oceania</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can, but you should add keyboard support and aria tags for accessibility

Comment: Yes, you can handle it with portals and useLayouteffect. However, I recommend using MUI Select or tailwind styles for your select cause making it with